# Help understanding these cake puns from a CNN Student News video

Tags: meaning, pun, word-play

The paragraph below is cited from [November 10th](http://edition.cnn.com/studentnews), starting at 9:39. [Here](http://transcripts.cnn.com/TRANSCRIPTS/1611/10/sn.01.html) is the transcript.

> Some might say it looks a little un-oven, or that its expression's a little frosty. But it's a cake artist's bread and butter and there's no getting a round the fact that it's one sweet sculpture, no ifs, pans or butter about it. 
>   This is CNN STUDENT NEWS where puns are a piece of cake.

I don't get the pun. (I've checked the dictionary, still don't get it.)

Please explain it to me, thank you.

Comment: Your link doesn't point to the article you cite, so I don't have any context, but the sentence is full of puns. Everything is a reference to cake.

Comment: It does point to the video. The transcript is cited from elsewhere though.

Comment: The official site hasn't released the latest transcript yet. Therefore you can't find it.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't see the video, because my Flash player needed updating. My bad.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The story refers to this cake.
[image]
Source: [Sad Trump cake is the perfect meme to end his campaign](http://www.theverge.com/2016/11/8/13570130/trump-cake-election-2016)

1. un-oven → uneven
2. 1. [frosty](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/frosty) - unfriendly or cold
   2. [frosting](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/frosting) - a sweet mixture, cooked or uncooked, for coating or filling cakes, cookies and the like; icing.
3. [bread and butter](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/bread+and+butter) - Fig. someone's basic income; someone's livelihood—the source of one's food
4. (Getting a) round -  I'm not sure about this one. I think it's intended to be a pun. Here are some possibilities:

   1. 1. Cakes are often round (circular).
      2. *Round* can be used to describe a face.
      3. [round](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/round) - a slice of food <*a round of bread*>
      4. The a *round* might refer to [sculpture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sculpture) in the round, as opposed to bas relief. (user:44539)
      5. "butter" cake and "round" cake are both types of cake. (user:5937)
   2. [*Getting around*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/get%20around) means to circumvent, evade.
5. sweet - slang. cool, awesome
6. no ifs, pans or butter → [no ifs, ands, or buts](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/no+ifs,+ands,+or+buts) - without excuses or doubts
7. [piece of cake](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/piece+of+cake) - Fig. something easy to do

Also, just before the quoted portion, the speaker says

> Some might pan its likeness

*Pans* are kitchen utensils, but [*pan*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pan) also means *to criticize severely*.

Comment: Thank you so much Max. I thought there were only one or two puns...

Comment: Turns out there're a lot.

Comment: I need some time to digest it. Does it sound funny to you, as a native speaker?

Comment: @JasmineKuo 

Comment: [round *n.*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/round#Noun), sense 7: **One sandwich (two full slices of bread with filling)**.

Comment: @TobySpeight I'm not sure, but I'm willing to see if others support that.

Comment: round... I decide to let it go. My brain has suffered enough for today. Thank you Toby.

Comment: The *a round* might refer to [sculpture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sculpture) in the round, as opposed to bas relief.

Comment: "butter" cake and "round" cake are both *types* of cake.

Comment: _Does it sound funny to you, as a native speaker?_ Not to me. Overdone and corny.

Comment: @AbraCadaver I think you meant to say "Overbun and cheesecakey"